How to turn a react native Flatlist with full screen items to a pdf
I have a react native screen that renders a Flatlist. Each item in the flatlist takes up the entire screen. I would like to turn this flatlist to a pdf, were each item is a page.
That can be easily done with react-native-view-shot and react-native-pdf by attaching a ref to each item and capturing it with view shot. My issue is since Flatlist renders items lazily, how do I make sure I capture all items even ones that are not yet loaded?
